# Problema con envio de mail

Tags: php, email

Estoy haciendo un formulario interno de mail y tengo el siguiente error:

`Warning: mail() has been disabled for security reasons in mail.php on line 19`

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mail.php:19) in mail.php on line 20`

formulario.php

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<div class="mb-3">
<input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
<textarea class="form-control" name="mensaje" rows="5" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
</div>

<button type="submit" name="enviar" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

mail.php

```
<?php

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

$destinatario = 'campo2@liquidacion.info';
$asunto = 'Liquidacion '.date('d/m/Y');

$carta = 'De: '.$nombre. '\n';
$carta.= 'Email: '.$email. '\n';
$carta.= 'Mensaje: '.$mensaje. '\n';

$cabeceras =    'From: campo2@liquidacion.info' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: no-replay@liquidacion.info' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($destinatario, $asunto, $carta, $cabeceras);
header('Location: liquidacion667.html');

?>
```

Agradesco de antemano la ayuda!

Comment: Pues eso. En la instalación de PHP que usas, deshabilitaron el uso de `mail()`, posiblemente usando la directiva `disable_functions`. Si tienes permisos, revisa si puedes habilitarla. Si no, te toca preguntar al admin del servidor

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo, pude ponerme en contacto con el soporte y me confirmo lo que tu dices. Me sugirieron que utilice phpMailer.

Comment: Súper! Ya te lo pongo como respuesta, para que otros sepan de qué va ese mensaje de error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la instalación de PHP que estás usando, deshabilitaron el uso de la función `mail()`, posiblemente usando la directiva `disable_functions` en el php.ini correspondiente.

Si tienes permisos, revisa si puedes habilitarla. Si no tienes permisos, te toca preguntar al admin del servidor sobre las directivas y permisos que hay disponibles para enviar emails.

Esta configuración es habitual, pues cualquier script que se filtre usando alguna vulnerabilidad, puede comenzar a enviar spam desde un servidor sin que el dueño se dé cuenta siquiera.